# Telerik MVC creating a template column with Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the latest version of Telerik MVC and ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Razor engine.

I am trying to create a template column with 2 links in it but I am getting an error.  Here is my code (with just 1 of the links in it):

```
column.Template(x =>
{
   @<text>
      <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(Url.AdministrationCategoryDetails(@x.Id))">Details</a>
   </text>;
})
   .Title("Action");
```

And here is my error:

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It either:

```
column.Template(x =>
   @<text>
      <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(Url.AdministrationCategoryDetails(x.Id))">Details</a>
   </text>
   )
   .Title("Action");
```

or simply:

```
column.Template(
   @<text>
      <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(Url.AdministrationCategoryDetails(item.Id))">Details</a>
   </text>
   )
   .Title("Action");
```

So remove the at sign (@) before `x.Id`, the semicolon and the braces. If you remove `x =>` as well, then the variable `x` becomes `item`.

Comment: That was the first thing that I did, then I put the @ in front of x.Id.